# Understanding Intel x86 assembly output for a modulo calculation

Tags: c, assembly, division, modulo

I have a school project about compilers and how it differs in assembly code between Intel x86 and ARMv7, but i'm stuck trying to comprehend the assembly for the Intel x86 architecture.

The source code is:

```
int main()
{
int a=5,b=2;
int result;
result = a % b;
printf("Result of 5 modulo 2 is %i\n", result);
}
```

Assembly output (gcc masm=Intel)

```
main:
/*
Intel32-x86 Arhchitecture
Little endian

ebp register -- base pointer
esp register -- stack pointer
*/
push    ebp ; ebp register put on stack
mov     ebp, esp ; Move data from ebp to esp
and     esp, -16 ; Logical AND ??
sub     esp, 32 ; Subtraction ??
mov     DWORD PTR [esp+20], 5 
;5 as 32 bits
;00000101-00000000-00000000-00000000
mov     DWORD PTR [esp+24], 2 
;2 as 32 bits
;00000010-00000000-00000000-00000000
mov     eax, DWORD PTR [esp+20]
mov     edx, eax
sar     edx, 31
;Shift Arithmetically right - edx med 31. 
;00000101-00000000-00000000-00000000 BEFORE
;00000000-00000000-00000000-00000000 AFTER
idiv    DWORD PTR [esp+24]
;Signed divide - IDIV r/m32 - EDX:EAX register
;Dividing EDX:EAX on value of esp+24, and save the remainder in edx.
;EDX:EAX 00000000-00000000-00000000-00000000-00000101-00000000-00000000-00000000
mov     DWORD PTR [esp+28], edx
mov     eax, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
mov     edx, DWORD PTR [esp+28]
mov     DWORD PTR [esp+4], edx
mov     DWORD PTR [esp], eax
call    printf
leave
ret
```

**and     esp, -16 ; Logical AND

sub     esp, 32 ; Subtraction**

What is the purpose of those two instructions?

Comment: `and esp, -16` is essentially the same as `and esp, 11111111 11111111 11111111 11110000`. Removing last 4 bits means rounding down to 16 byte boundary. The is mostly done for performance reasons (see also `data structure alignment`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose is mentioned in the comments:

```
        and     esp,-16    ;round esp down to 16 byte boundary
        sub     esp,32     ;allocate 32 bytes of space for local variables
```

In case you didn't catch this part about sign extending the dividend:

```
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [esp+20] ; eax = dividend
        mov     edx, eax   ; edx = dividend
        sar     edx, 31    ; edx = 0 or -1 (the sign extension)
```